# chrome extension : How to get key events

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to get key events in a google chrome extension file - `background.html` - ?

```js
document.onkeydown = function () {
  alert('test')
};
```

Previous code doesn't work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I assume you want to implement hotkeys for your extension. Your code should in fact work, except it works on the background page, which is usually not open to catch key presses.

To catch keypresses globally, or at least on web pages, you will have to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that sends [messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background page. The content script is injected to the open web page and insert methods for catching keypresses, and then send a message to the background page with information on which keys are pressed.

Comment: However injection doesn't work on many pages, like chrome urls, pdf documents, etc.

Answer (score 64):

Not sure if this is still active, but an update might help someone like me who is just now playing around with Chrome extensions. The new [commands api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) allows you to receive the same functionality without using a content script.

Use your manifest.json file to register the keyboard commands. For example:

```
...    
"commands": {
    "save" : {
        "suggested_key": {
             "default": "Alt+Shift+S" 
        },
        "description": "Save a link"
    },
    "random": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Alt+Shift+L"
        },
        "description": "Load a random link"
    }
}
...
```

and then you can catch it in your background page

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    if (command === "save") {
        alert("save");
    } else if (command === "random") {
        alert("random");
    }
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: But that allows only 4 hotkeys.

Comment: This requires only certain keys to be used and the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> has to be part of it. I find this inconvenient for the users of my extension so I'm going to try to detect keys directly in content.

Comment: Unfortunately, this API is seriously limited by the list of keys that can be registered. From your developer.chrome.com link: "Supported keys: A-Z, 0-9, Comma, Period, Home, End, PageUp, PageDown, Space, Insert, Delete, Arrow keys (Up, Down, Left, Right) and the Media Keys (MediaNextTrack, MediaPlayPause, MediaPrevTrack, MediaStop)."

Comment: @PatrickDark, The worst is you cant register the key by itself without Ctrl. Basically, it's useless.

Comment: In other words, its not a good replacement for **real key events**.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'd need to have a **background** JavaScript file, which in this case I'll call popup.js. And that'll include the code you gave:

```
document.onkeydown = function() {
  // what you want to on key press.
};
```

Then you want to include this as a background Script file in your manifest.json:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "popup.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": [ 
        "popup.js"
       ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the key strokes from `contentScript.js` and then pass it as variable using `chrome.runtime.SendMessage()`.

**For example:**

Add below piece of code inside `contentScript.js` file

```
window.addEventListener('keypress',function(key){
console.log(key.key)
let keyvalue = key.key
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(null,keyvalue,(response)=>{
console.log("Sent key value"+response)
        })
    })
```

Inside `background.js` file place below piece of code,

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message,sender,sendResponse)=>{
    console.log(message)
    console.log(sender)
    sendResponse("Received message in background!!")
})
```

Now you will get the key strokes as you type. In background console you can view them like below.
[image: background.js console log]