# How can I display keyboard shortcuts to the context menu options created by my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension adds few context menu options and like other options that appear by default on right click, I also wish to display the keyboard shortcuts to be used to trigger my context menu options. Also, I can make use of content scripts for keyboard shortcut implementation but is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: For the second part of your question, see the answer about the `commands` API on [chrome extension : How to get key events](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5498893/710446)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding display of shortcuts: it's an old, sadly untriaged [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142840). As of now, it's not possible.

Regarding keyboard shortcuts, there is a specific API, [`commands` API](https:///developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands).

(Edit: fixed link URL)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. You have been helping me a lot by answering my queries on chrome extension. Is it okay if I can get in touch with you and have a conversation with you for some concrete understanding of somethings related to chrome extensions?

Comment: Usually, _no_. But let's see if it can work. Please post some contact information on your profile, I'll contact you.

Comment: Done. You can check the info under website