# Adding keyboard shortcut to context menu for Google Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm trying to make an extension and which uses `chrome.contextMenu`. I create a contextMenu element and it works fine, but now I'm wondering if it is possible to add a keyboard shortcut to my element? I've looked through the documentation but could not find anything. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the commands API to add keyboard shortcuts that trigger actions in your extension. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands

Comment: That was actually my first attempt at executing the actions I wanted in my extension. However, I opted for using contextMenu because I couldn't get the highlighted text when using commands.

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, no.  There is an open feature request for it from 2012.

[Issue 142840 in chromium: Add "shortcut" property to chrome.contextMenus API](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/4gCRpk4-12M)

> Reported by ja...@kiwi-themes.com, Aug 15, 2012
>
> For native-like experience it should be possible to specify shortcut text for each menu item. E.g. if you create "Copy" menu item then there should be also "Ctrl+C" shortcut text shown next to it.
>
> Proposed API:
>
> ```
>    chrome.contextMenus.create({
>       title: 'Copy',
>       shortcut: 'Ctrl+C',
>       id: 'copy',
>       contexts: ['all']
>  });
> ```

also see [How can I display keyboard shortcuts to the context menu options created by my chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121329/how-can-i-display-keyboard-shortcuts-to-the-context-menu-options-created-by-my-c)

I would also love to see a way to underline one of the letters in a custom context menu listing for ALT access but that appears to also be unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is you can create commands and assign shortcut keys. You can make the context menu item and the command trigger the same functionality.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/