# How to trigger a command defined in another extension with chrome.commands

Tags: events, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that listens keydown on ctrl+shift+u.

If I trigger an event ctrl+shift+u in a content script, the plugin's listener won't fire.

```
// ( I am using jQuery )

var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown" );

            e.which = 85;
            e.keyCode = 85;
            e.shiftKey = true;
            e.ctrlKey = true;

$( document ).trigger( e );
```

How can I properly trigger this event? ( preferably from a content script or from another extension )

*I would not say this question is a duplicate. I succeeded to trigger the event, only the extension's handler won't fire. This question rather refers to emulating browser actions, not content-based events.*

**UPDATE:**

The extension that listens the event is a third party software, there is no way to dig inside it's code. This keyboard event can be configured on browser-level in chrome://extensions/configureCommands

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Comment: If that key is defined as a Chrome extension key on `chrome://extensions` page then you won't be able to trigger it programmatically.

Comment: Apparently you have to use a content script that catches the events and send them to the background process http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498893/chrome-extension-how-to-get-key-events

Comment: have you tried `chrome.commands` API? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands

Comment: As far as I see, this API rather refers to listening than triggering the event. Please, feel free to correct me

Comment: You need to be more descriptive in what you're trying to do. Do you have an extension that somehow listens to this (how)? Is it a third-party extension? Needs more details.

Comment: Please, read my update

Comment: So you're creating an extension that should trigger a keydown in a different extension?  You may need to trigger a native keydown, and not a jQuery keydown.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do exactly what You've described. I am just not sure if any triggers in the content document will actually trigger the browser-level event. Maybe a chrome API does, but I did not succeed to find it.

Comment: Any suggestions to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your question is thus: *How to trigger a command defined in another extension with `chrome.commands`*

That is not possible from extension code if you don't control the extension receiving the event.

You may have success with a [Native Host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), but that's a very roundabout route.

Comment: Thank You, Xan, I have edited my question. Native host might be a way to go.